# How to implement paging in ranking query?

Tags: mysql, pagination

I am trying to implement a ranking with MySQL. I have found a good article about it without using self joins ([ranking without self join](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join)).

```
SELECT
  score_id, student_name, score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := score,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM
  score,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Regarding that I will have a lot of rankings it would be nice to add paging.
First idea was to use `LIMIT`, but it fails (rank isn't continued, so it starts with one again).

I can't just multiple the page with the limit, because it is possible to have scores multiple times.

How can I achieve paging with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution working for me.

I have added a new column **rank** to the table and calculate the rank with an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE score s, (
        SELECT
          score_id, student_name, score,
          @prev := @curr,
          @curr := score,
          @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
        FROM
          score,
          (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
        ORDER BY score DESC
    ) r
        SET s.rank = r.rank WHERE s.score_id = r.score_id
```

Now, it is easily possible to limit the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do it similar to LIMIT, by adding an outer query, like so:

```
SELECT score_id, student_name, score, rank
FROM 
(SELECT
   score_id, student_name, score,
   @prev := @curr,
   @curr := score,
   @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
 FROM
   score,
   (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
 ORDER BY score DESC) AS b
WHERE rank BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Then you could do `BETWEEN 11 AND 20`, etc. for the subsequent pages.  Might not be the best way to do it, but it is one way :)

Comment: Doh ... I was thinking too complex, but we will see if there are "better" approaches. :)

Comment: Interesting, there is no other answer yet. So it seems that your way is the "best". :)